# How to add and remove items between select box in vue js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

Html:

Select box:1

```
    <select v-model="facilitySelected" name="facilities" multiple="multiple" id="facilities" size="4" class="form-control">
      <option v-for="availability in availableFacilities" v-bind:value="availability">{{availability.label}}--</option>
    </select>
```

Click Events:

```
<a @click="removeFacilities" class="btn btn-default remove_option" rel="facilities2" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>

        <a @click="addFacilities" class="btn btn-default add_option" rel="facilities2" id="add"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

Select Box:2

```
 <select name="facilities" multiple="multiple" id="facilities2" size="4" class="form-control">
      <option v-for="facility in selectedFacilities" v-bind:value="facility.value">{{facility.label}}</option>
    </select>
```

And the script was,

```
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      facilitySelected:[],
      availableFacilities: [{
        value: 1,
        label: 'Double (Non a/c)'
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        label: 'Premium Double (a/c)'
      },
      {
        value: 3,
        label: 'Standard Double (a/c)'
      }
    ],
    selectedFacilities: [],
  }
},


methods:{


  addFacilities() {
    this.selectedFacilities = this.facilitySelected.concat(this.selectedFacilities);
  },

  removeFacilities() {

  },

}

}
```

Here i have two select boxes with click events in between, I have assigned the values to the variable to the first select box option. My requirement is when i select a `option` from `first select box` and click over the `addFacilities` click event, the data in that particular option should be `moved to second select box` and when i select `option` in `second select box` and click over `removeFacilities`, the data needs to move to `first select box`.

For adding `first to second` i tried with,

```
  addFacilities() {
    this.selectedFacilities = this.facilitySelected.concat(this.selectedFacilities);
  },
```

It moving the data to second select box but that data still remaining in first select box, how should i remove this `duplication` and here i am using `concat` to add the data.
If i select the option and click addFacilities, that option should be removed from the `first select box` and vice versa for `removeFacilities` also.

The fiddle link was, https://jsfiddle.net/rym9j2ch/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you actually want to move items between arrays, you can do it this way. I cleaned code a bit to concentrate only on this.

Html:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="availableFacilitiesSelectedValues" multiple="multiple">
    <option v-for="facility in availableFacilities" v-bind:value="facility.value">{{facility.text}}</option>
  </select>
  <select v-model="selectedFacilitiesSelectedValues" multiple="multiple">
    <option v-for="facility in selectedFacilities" v-bind:value="facility.value">{{facility.text}}</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <a @click.prevent="addFacilities" href="#">add</a>
  <br/>
  <a @click.prevent="removeFacilities" href="#">remove</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    availableFacilities: [{
      value: 1,
      text: 'Double (Non a/c)',
    }, {
      value: 2,
      text: 'Premium Double (a/c)',
    }, {
      value: 3,
      text: 'Standard Double (a/c)',
    }, ],
    selectedFacilities: [],
    availableFacilitiesSelectedValues: [], // Facility values, selected in first control
    selectedFacilitiesSelectedValues: [], // Facility values, selected in second control
  },
  methods: {
    move(value, arrFrom, arrTo) { // Helper function to transfer facility from one array to another by 'value' property
        var index = arrFrom.findIndex(function(el) {
          return el.value == value;
        });
        var item = arrFrom[index];

        arrFrom.splice(index, 1);
        arrTo.push(item);
      },
      addFacilities() {
        var selected = this.availableFacilitiesSelectedValues.slice(0);

        for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; ++i) {
          this.move(selected[i], this.availableFacilities, this.selectedFacilities);
        }
      },
      removeFacilities() {
        var selected = this.selectedFacilitiesSelectedValues.slice(0);

        for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; ++i) {
          this.move(selected[i], this.selectedFacilities, this.availableFacilities);
        }
      },
  }
})
```

Working fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/9x0s73gk/

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      facilitySelected:[],
      availableFacilities: [{
        value: 1,
        label: 'Double (Non a/c)',
        selected: false,
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        label: 'Premium Double (a/c)'
        selected: false,
      },
      {
        value: 3,
        label: 'Standard Double (a/c)'
        selected: false,
      }
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    selectedFacilities() {
      return this.availableFacilities.filter(f => f.selected);
    },
    unselectedFacilities() {
      return this.availableFacilities.filter(f => !f.selected);
    },
  }
},
```

And bind your `<select>`s to 2 computed list accordingly. When add/remove is clicked you just set the *selected* property of the items to true/false.

By the way, what you're trying to implement looks very much like a `transfer` component. For example: http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/transfer.

Comment: Can you provide some fiddle for it to get a better view?

Answer (score 1):

I changed some parts in your code and then it worked.
I think the reason why it didn't work is related to `v-bind:value="facility.value"`, you bound object in first select box but integer value in second one. It made values bound by each `v-model` differed in types.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/rym9j2ch/1/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    facilitySelected1: [],
    facilitySelected2: [],
    availableFacilities: [{
        value: 1,
        text: 'Double (Non a/c)'
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        text: 'Premium Double (a/c)'
      },
      {
        value: 3,
        text: 'Standard Double (a/c)'
      }
    ],
    selectedFacilities: [],
  },
  methods: {
    removeFacilities() {
      this.selectedFacilities = this.selectedFacilities.filter(fac => !this.facilitySelected2.includes(fac));
      this.availableFacilities = [...this.availableFacilities, ...this.facilitySelected2];
      this.facilitySelected2 = [];
    },
    addFacilities() {
      this.availableFacilities = this.availableFacilities.filter(fac => !this.facilitySelected1.includes(fac));
      this.selectedFacilities = [...this.selectedFacilities, ...this.facilitySelected1];
      this.facilitySelected1 = [];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="facilitySelected1" multiple="multiple" id="facilities" size="4" class="form-control">
  <option v-for="availability in availableFacilities" :value="availability">{{availability.text}}</option>
</select>

<a @click="removeFacilities" class="btn btn-default remove_option" rel="facilities2" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
<a @click="addFacilities" class="btn btn-default add_option" rel="facilities2" id="add"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
<select  v-model="facilitySelected2" multiple="multiple" id="facilities2" size="4" class="form-control">
  <option v-for="facility in selectedFacilities" :value="facility">{{facility.text}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution I made:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lfd6j90c/2/

I've changed some of your code

```js
        new Vue({
          el: "#app",
          data: {
            add: [],
            remove: [],
            facilitySelected: [],
            availableFacilities: [{
              value: 1,
              text: 'Double (Non a/c)'
            }, {
              value: 2,
              text: 'Premium Double (a/c)'
            }, {
              value: 3,
              text: 'Standard Double (a/c)'
            }]
          },
    
    
          methods: {
    
    
            addFacilities() {
                var af = this.availableFacilities;
                var fs = this.facilitySelected;
                this.add.forEach(function(element) {
               fs.push(af[element]);
               af.splice(element, 1);
                });
                this.availableFacilities = af;
                this.facilitySelected = fs;
              },
    
            removeFacilities() {
                var af = this.availableFacilities;
                var fs = this.facilitySelected;
                this.remove.forEach(function(element) {
               af.push(fs[element]);
               fs.splice(element, 1);
                });
                this.availableFacilities = af;
                this.facilitySelected = fs;
              }
    
          }
        })
```

```html
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <div id="app">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
              <select v-model="add" multiple="multiple" size="4" class="form-control">
                <option v-for="(item, index) in availableFacilities" v-bind:value="index">
                  {{ item.text }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 ">
              <button @click="removeFacilities" class="btn btn-default remove_option" rel="facilities2" id="remove"><</button>
              <button @click="addFacilities" class="btn btn-default add_option" rel="facilities2" id="add">></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
              <select v-model="remove" multiple="multiple" size="4" class="form-control">
                <option v-for="(item, index) in facilitySelected" v-bind:value="index">
                  {{ item.text }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
    
          </div>
    
        </div>
```